# How 'while loop' memory works in C programming?

Tags: c, memory, while-loop, programming-languages

I'm trying to find out if my understanding of the way this simple program works is correct.
    It works I just want to make sure I understand why.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int x, y = 0, z;
        x = 123;

        while(x != 0){
            z = x % 10;
            y = y * 10 + z;
            x /= 10;
        }

        printf(">>> %d", y);
        return 0;
    }

    output
    >>> 321
```

I think it goes like this.

So "x" was originally declared with a value of 123 
 is taken by the loop along with the condition that 
 states while x is not equal to 0 the program continues.

Loop starts and from the original declaration 
 "x" takes what is in memory 123 and "z" is assigned value:
 the remainder of the following operations;
 123 % 10 = 12.3 leaving "z" containing 3

This is how the last number becomes the first number
 memory now contains 12.

"y" takes what is in memory 12 and is multiplied by 10 
 totaling 120 added to "z" which is 3 
 so memory now contains 123.

Then "x" takes what is in memory 123 / 10
 totaling 12.3 = 12. 
 So memory now contains 12

Loop starts from previous iteration 
 "x" takes what is in memory 12 and "z" is assigned value:
 the remainder following operations; 12 % 10 = 2.

This is where the second to last number becomes the second number.
 So memory now contains 1.

Then "y" takes what is in memory 1 * 10 = 10 2 which is "z"
 so memory now contains 12.

Then "x" takes what is in memory 12 / 10 = 1.2 
 and returns only the quotient of 1. 
 So memory now contains 1.

Loop starts from previous iteration
 "x" takes what is in memory 1 and "z" is assigned value: 
the remainder of the following operations;
 1 % 10 = 0.1 leaving z containing 1.

This is where the first number becomes the last number.
 So memory now contains 0.

"y" takes what is in memory 0 * 10 = 0 + 1 which is "z".
 so memory now contains 1.

"x" takes what is in memory 1 / 10 = 0.1
 division operator returns only the quotient.
 So memory now contains 0.

Now "x" = 0  sothe condition has been met
 and the program breaks.

So if any one can tell me if I'm right or 
 explain to me where I went wrong and help me 
 see the concepts correctly, I would really 
 appreciate their insights.

Thank you.

Comment: That's quite a verbose description. Perhaps it would have been a good idea to post the code you're describing :-)

Comment: Please show your code, else we cant comment if your interpretation is correct or not

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .
Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: There is NO imaginary memory  in C .What you are assuming is wrong : Specially `So memory now contains 12`

Comment: Vagish I did not know what was going on that is why I asked. @Jonathan Leffler gave great answer though. Thank you for your insight as well. Noted no imaginary memory in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is off (rather badly off).  The section '…leaving behind the quotient so memory now contains 12.
Then y takes what is in memory 12…' is singularly weird.  The division is done using integer arithmetic, not floating point.  There's a moderate chance there's a register somewhere containing `12`, but it isn't multiplied by 10 or anything, and the presence or absence of the `12` is immaterial to the rest of the code (unless the compiler manages to use it instead of executing a second division for `x /= 10`).

#### More accurate version of the logic

The actual logic is more like:

- `x == 123` means `x != 0` so the code goes through the loop:

  - `z = 123 % 10` means `z == 3`.
  - `y = 0 * 10 + 3` means `y == 3`.
  - `x /= 10` means `x == 12`.
- `x == 12` means `x != 0` so the code goes through the loop:

  - `z = 12 % 10` means `z == 2`.
  - `y = 3 * 10 + 2` means `y == 32`.
  - `x /= 10` means `x == 1`.
- `x == 1` means `x != 0` so the code goes through the loop:

  - `z = 1 % 10` means `z == 1`.
  - `y = 32 * 10 + 1` means `y == 321`.
  - `x /= 10` means `x == 0`
- `x == 0` means the loop terminates:

  - the value of `y` is `321`.

#### Using print statements to see how the code runs

Note that you could have spared yourself some angst by adding suitable printing to the code.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x, y = 0, z;
    x = 123;

    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    while(x != 0){
        z = x % 10;
        printf("z = %d\n", z);
        y = y * 10 + z;
        printf("y = %d\n", y);
        x /= 10;
        printf("x = %d\n", x);
    }
    printf(">>> %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

You could also learn to step through the code with a debugger to see the values in `x`, `y`, and `z` as it goes through the loop.  I find using `printf()` statements helpful — the coding I do usually lends itself to that sort of debugging.  If you develop GUI programs, it is probably less helpful, or requires more care in the setup (where the information is printed) to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leffler your very helpful explanation